# Paranormal romance: half-were half-fey hybrid who mates with wereleopard

Tags: story-identification, books

This is a paranormal romance about a young woman who grows up believing she's human only to find out she's a half were half fey hybrid and ends up getting mated to a wereleopard with heterochromia. At the end, she gets nabbed.

Comment: Please, be more specific!  Anything else you have is useful.  What kind of book--parberback, hardcover?  When was it published?  ...  Any info you have...

Comment: @CHEESE The tags suggest it's a book.

Comment: @Randal'Thor ohhh yes, how clever

Comment: Seduced by Moonlight by Laurell K. Hamilton? - "*Me, a mongrel, only half fey and part mortal. The Unseelie court has suffered for so long, and there are some who would not have it weakened further by an impure queen. My enemies grow in number every day. But they do not know what I am capable of. Nor, for that matter, do I. . . . In Seduced by Moonlight, Laurell K. Hamilton brings the dark, erotic reign of the immortal fey to a startling new depth*"

Answer (score 1):

kinda sounds like one of the dark hunter books by Sherrilyn Kenyon... actually it sounds like it could be almost anything by Sherrilyn Kenyon